# flutter packages get: won't re-authenticate after failed bitbucket password

Tags: git, bitbucket, package, flutter

I have a self-made flutter package hosted privately on bitbucket for work.  When trying to import said package into a new project, `flutter packages get` asked me for my bitbucket account credentials (which is correct, because it's https auth, instead of ssh), but I accidentally entered the wrong information, and `Ctrl-C`'d my way out of it to try again.  Now when I try, it doesn't even try to authenticate and complains that it couldn't find the file I'm trying to import from the package...

Here's the pubspec.yaml for the project trying to import the package:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  widgets:
    git:
      url: https://bitbucket.org/my-library.git
      path: widgets/
```

Here's the exact error:

```
Could not find a file named "widgets/pubspec.yaml" in 
https://bitbucket.org/my-library.git 
12bbaba9.......................db15eed403f09.
```

And finally, here's the tree structure of said widget library:

```
.   
├── README.md
├── utils
│   ├── img.svg
│   └── list_to_svg.dart
└── widgets
    ├── analysis_options.yaml
    ├── android
    ├── build
    ├── ios 
    ├── lib  <-- stuff in here ...
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── pubspec.lock
    ├── pubspec.yaml
    ├── README.md
    ├── test
    ├── widgets_android.iml
    └── widgets.iml
```

Main question is: **how do I get flutter packages to try authenticating again?**

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Creating another brand new project and importing from there works and compiles, I just **have** to get my password right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I've already found a solution.  Sorry for bothering, but I'll leave this up in case anyone else runs into this.

1. Comment out the dependency from `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter packages get`.  This effectively removes the package.
2. uncommented said dependency, then run `flutter packages get` again.  It should re-authenticate this time.

Comment: Also delete cached directory "/PATH_TO_FLUTTER/.pub-cache/git/cache/REPO_NAME-REPO_REVISION".